# How Best to Create a System Context Diagram in Sparx Systems Enterprise Architect

Tags: diagram, enterprise-architect

I would like to create a system context diagram in Enterprise Architect similar to what appears in here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/System_context_diagram.
I am wondering if use case model is the way to go, or if there is some system engineering model that would be more appropriate.

Answer (score 0):

Honestly, no. Use cases are about added value. The System Context Diagram is more about interfaces and actors. From my POV a crude mixture. You can use any diagram (e.g. a class diagram) in EA and stuff it with boundaries and elements from the White Board MDG. But I'd never do that.

If you're going to design a new system, start with plain requirements, synthesize use cases and design a system based on that.

If you RE systems start with components and identify interfaces, simultaneously trying to join with a use case model.